# Nifi querydatabase table error

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi

I am trying to load data from table into hadoop using nifi querydatabase table processor.

**Steps:**

1. I configured processor according to the document.
2. Load connector jar into nifi lib directory.

**Controller service configuration properties:**
[image]

I am getting the following error:

> can't load database driver exception.

Comment: Run processor after set the driver location like file:///C:/tmp/postgresql-connector-jdbc4.jar or move that postgres jar into NIFI\Lib directory then restart services and then run processor

Answer (score 1):

The PostgreSQL driver name should be org.postgresql.Driver, not com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver. Looks like a copy-paste-overwrite from the MySQL driver? In any case, you should be good with org.postgresql.Driver, and if you still see errors, check the file at logs/nifi-app.log, it should include more information about why it can't load the driver (look for the above text, then "Caused by" underneath).